# Insert after count with node JS and MongoDB save nul records

Tags: node.js, mongodb, insert, count

I am trying to save strings from a array to a collection, I save the string in the collection if this did not exist before, but after saving the string, this is null

Here is my source code:

```
exports.procc = function(req, res) {
         //combinatorial is the array that contains the strings
            var k = combinatorial.length, m = 0;
            var collection = db.collection('searchtb');
            collection.count({'search': b}, function(err, count) {

              for (m = 0; m < k; m++) {
                                        //Here prints the value of the varible
                                        console.log(combinatorial[m]);
                                        //Here the same variable is null
                                        collection.count({'search': combinatorial[m]}, function(err, count) {
                                              c=count;
                                              if(c==0){
                                               collection.insert({'search': combinatorial[m],'hits':1}); 
                                              }                                        
                                         });
                                    }

            });
     res.end();
    };
```

But, if I write the following code without 'count' the strings save in correct way.

```
 for (m = 0; m < k; m++) {
                          collection.insert({'search': combinatorial[m],'hits':1}); 
                         }
```

I don´t know what is my error.
Thanks for your help

Comment: You should initialize the variable c. Or at least define it as a variable.

Comment: I forgot to write 'C', but it's initialized and that is not the problem

Comment: Maybe it's because `count` doesn't eq `0`. Never...

Comment: Have you tried debugging the value of count or c inside the callback function during the if-statement?

Comment: Yes, it's 0, because the variable 'combinatorial[m]' is null in this line -> collection.count({'search': combinatorial[m]}

Comment: It's not so strightforward. Collection could have documents (records) with `search` == null

Comment: But the problem is that the array combinatorial does not contains null values and in this line-> collection.count({'search': combinatorial[m]}, function(err, count) {
                                              c=count;
                                              if(c==0){
                                               collection.insert({'search': combinatorial[m],'hits':1}); 
                                              }                                        
                                         });-> combinatorial[m] becomes null

Comment: At what time the value is null? When you call the count function or inside the callback function when inserting ? You have to remember that it's asynchronous so value of m could be anything inside the callback function. Also it's scary to use the variable named count since your whole loop is already inside a callback-function which has a local variable named count.

Comment: When I call count function and inside the callback, I know is that it's asynchronous, but I have no idea to resolve this, because I have to traverse all the array to compare if the string exists and the problem is with 'combinatorial[m]', because 'm' takes always the length of the array combinatorial and so that always return null values